# How to add/subtract date in log4j 2?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

```
i have following configuration file in log4j 2


<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/test.log" 
        filePattern="logs$${date:yyyyMM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log">
                    <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{4} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
                    <Policies>
                        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB"/>
                    </Policies>
                    <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="max" max="100"/>
                </RollingFile>
```

can I perform date addition and/or subtraction in the filePattern. ? as of now the files generated upon rollover has current date. I would like to subtract single day from it . how can it be done ?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible, but I believe someone requested something similar earlier. I believe filing your request on the Log4j-2.0 issue tracker ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2 ) may be the best way to proceed.